# Computing conditional expectation for a Poisson process

Tags: probability

It's been a few years since I took my last probability class, and I am brushing up on some basics of random processes.  I am working through a book and am stuck with deriving a conditional expectation for a Poisson process.  It gives the expression
$$
E[N_t|N_s] = N_s + \lambda(t-s),
$$
for $0 \leq s < t$, where $N_t$ is the value of the process at time $t$ with mean $\lambda$.  I have tried deriving this but I'm not really sure where to start.  I get as far as
$$
E[X_t|X_s] = \sum_n n \frac{P(N_t = n, N_s = m)}{P(N_s = m)}
$$
The denominator is thus $\frac{(\lambda s)^m e^{-s\lambda}}{m!}$, but I am hung up on the conditional Poisson part -- any pointers on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that $N_t-N_s$ is independent of $N_s$ for $0\le s<t$ (a defining property of the Poisson process $(N_t)_{t\ge 0}$), one gets

$$E(N_t-N_s)=E(N_t-N_s\mid N_s)=E(N_t\mid N_s)-N_s$$

Therefore, $$E(N_t\mid N_s)=E(N_t-N_s)+N_s$$

Comment: thank you -- the independent increments was something I overlooked in the derivation.